# A linear operator on Wasserstein spaces

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, optimal-transport

Let $(S,d)$ be a Polish space, and let $p\in[1,\infty)$. We define $$P=\left\{\mu:\mu \text{ is a probability measure on } S \text{ s.t. } \int_Sd(x,y)^pdy<\infty \text{ for every } x\in S\right\}.$$ Let $\pi$ be a transition kernel on $S$, and let $\mu\in P$. How can we show $\pi\mu\in P$, where $$\pi\mu(B)=\int_S\pi(x,B)\mu(dx)?$$

Comment: What conditions are you placing on $\pi$?  In general it won't be true for all transition kernels $\pi$.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Do you know which conditions would be sufficient for this statement?

Comment: Not really, sorry.  You might be able to get something if you have sufficiently fast decay of $\pi(y, B(y,r)^c)$ as $r \to \infty$, which would say in some sense that the tails of the "transition density" are not too heavy.  But I don't know of any specific results offhand.  If you could say what sort of conditions you have in mind, it might help.